# react-vr integrate a button for enter in vr mode

Tags: react-360

**Problem:**

hi, my problem is that i should include a button for enter in a vr mode how with a-frame or krpano and i have see in a video on youtube this button in an exemple

[image]

but around the web I could not find a way or a guide to activate the "view in vr" button of react-vr.

In my project I have active only these buttons, both desktop and smartphone.

[image]
[image]

**Question:**

How i can include the button view in vr in my project?
[image]

> Thank you very much for your help (I'm not a native English speaker so
>   sorry if something is not clear)

Answer (score 1):

The button is not shown in your project, because your browser does not natively support WebVR. Here is a list of [supported browsers](https://webvr.rocks/). For all other versions you have to embed [webvr-polyfill](https://github.com/immersive-web/webvr-polyfill) to enable switching between vr and non-vr mode.